# Classical inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been playing around with inheritance in JavaScript and I'm wondering if there are any drawbacks to this method which tries to emulate classical inheritance from C-based languages.

```
Function.prototype.extends = function (parentClass) {
    function temp () { this.constructor = this; };
    temp.prototype = new parentClass();

    this.prototype = new temp();
};

var Animal = function() {
    function Animal() {};

    Animal.prototype.walk = function () {
        return this.name + ' walks';
    };

    return Animal;
}();


var Cat = function () {
    function Cat (name) {
        this.name = name;
    };

    Cat.extends(Animal);

    Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
        return this.name + ' meows';
    };

    return Cat;
}();

var Chester = new Cat('Chester');

console.log(Chester.meow()); // Chester meows
console.log(Chester.walk()); // Chester walks
```

This is a crude example, but can anyone point out any glaring problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hang on a tick... there *is* a problem here that, weirdly nobody has noticed. I will admit that this is hardly ever used, but still: 
In a normal JS prototypal inheritance scenario, you would be able to pull stunts like these:

```
var Animal = (function()
{
    function Animal()
    {
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
    };
    Animal.prototype.walk = function()
    {
        return this.name + ' is walking';
    };
    return Animal;
}()):
var Cat = (function(parent)
{
    function Cat(name)
    {
        this.name = name || this.constructor.name;
    };
    Cat.prototype = new Animal;
    Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
    Cat.prototype.sleep = function()
    {
        return this.name + ' is sleeping';
    };
    return Cat;
}(Animal));
var garfield = new Cat('Garfield');
//code
var newSameClass = new garfield.constructor();
```

Whereas the `extends` method you have written causes infinite constructor recursion: you're declaring a new function, that uses the `this` keyword... but *because* it's being used with the `new` keyword, it creates a new instance of itself (`temp`).
In the constructor of `temp`, all it does is equate its prototype to its own instance... ***you create an object that is its own prototype*** and therefore effectively is not part of any chain (it keeps on pointing to itself) and for some bizarre reason, you expect this to keep track of the *constructor*? I think what you ought to write is this:

```
Function.prototype.extends = function(parentClass)
{
    var temp = this.prototype.constructor;
    this.prototype = new ParentClass;
    this.prototype.constructor = temp;
};
```

Which works just fine, and doesn't require some temp constructor/object at any point.
Just try it with this simple example:

```
function Animal(){};
function Cow(){};
Cow.extends(Animal);
function Bird(){};
function Chicken(){};
Bird.extends(Animal);
Chicken.extends(Bird);
var dinner = new Chicken();
console.log(dinner instanceof Animal);//true -- sorry vegetarians
console.log(dinner instanceof Cow);//false -- no beef tonight
console.log(dinner instanceof Bird);//true -- mmm, poultry
console.log(dinner instanceof Chicken);//true -- roasted, probably
```

Which is, I take it, what you wanted.
PS: I would strongly advise you *not* to augment prototypes you don't *own*. By that I mean `Object`, `Array`, `Function`, `Date` and the like... Save for a few cases where the `String` prototype poses X-browser issues (`String.trim` wasn't implemented in IE8, for example).
You might encounter issues with other toolkits/libs, future updates, issues depending on the implementation (IE, FF and V8 deal with native prototypes differently in some cases)

All in all, it's best to leave them be... I see no reason why you shouldn't simply write a function, and *not* attach it to the prototype. Or, if needs must, do what ECMA is doing: all these `createObject`-like thingies go into one big bin: `Object` as in `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and `Object.getPrototypeOf()`. What's so difficult about:

```
function extend(child, parent)
{
    var prto, Object.getPrototypeOf(child),
        tmp = prto.constructor;
    prto = new parent;
    prto.constructor = tmp;
    return child;//<-- this might be handy
}
//usage:
var garfield = new (extends(Cat, Animal))('garfield');
```

Comment: Thanks again! Weirdly I had picked up on infinite constructor recursion and the solution is a carbon copy of your suggestion. The original method was also exactly the same as your `extend(child, parent)` method. This was just an experiment to emulate the syntactical sugar of C-based languages, or rather, a more intuitive way of writing this extends that.

Comment: @IanBrindley: You're welcome... if you don't mind my asking: since stack-exchange sites aim to be a reference for future users, googling a specific problem, you might want to reconsider which answer is up-voted/accepted here. Since I mention the infinite recursion, and suggest a different approach that, by your own admission, is what you've ended up using, then perhaps this answer should be the one marked as accepted? (PS: as for the answer to your other, PHP, question: I know I'm a bit of a rep-whore, but an up-vote for my efforts would be greatly appreciated ;-P)

Answer (score 1):

Observations:

- You changed the Function prototype, which is generally considered bad practice.
- The inheritance does work, `instanceof` checks work fine
- I do not see how it emulates classical inheritance better than this:

  ```
  var Cat = function () {

    function Cat (name) {
      Animal.call(this); //This takes care of inheritance, classic JS
      this.name = name;
    };
    //Fix prototype
    Cat.prototype = new Animal();
    Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

    Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
      return this.name + ' meows';
    };

    return Cat;
  }();
  ```

Except that you are more explicit and less verbose in declaring the inheritance.
I guess it is a matter of style at this point, I would stick with the old school.

Comment: This is not a complete example and it doesn't establish inheritance. Try `Chester.walk()` for example.

Comment: Fixed, so I guess the question is, is that function saving three lines worth it? I would guess not.

Comment: @tomdemuyt Thanks for your answer. I appreciate that extending the `Function` prototype may be frowned upon, but I do feel that this method feels a lot more intuitive when writing. My only concern really was that it might cause havoc with the prototype chain.